# JTextArea - enable edit only at the end of document

Tags: java, swing, mouseevent, jtextarea

I use a `JTextArea` where using double click I can able to select the word at any place but I don't want to enable edit. Which means text can be entered only at the end of text area and not anywhere in between.

I have tried with mouse listeners like below:

```
@Override
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent me) {
       if(SwingUtilities.isLeftMouseButton(me)){
        System.err.println("clicked");
        int pos = textArea.getCaretPosition();
        if(pos < textArea.getDocument().getLength()){
            textArea.setCaretPosition(textArea.getDocument().getLength());
        }
    }
   }
```

This makes double click not to select the word. I understand it is because caret position is moved to end. But how can I achieve this?

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete and Verifiable Example).

Comment: I can see a `DocumentFilter` in your future...

Comment: *"text can be entered only at the end of text area and not anywhere in between."*  ..Why?  If I type ten lines of text and spot an error in the 3rd line, I'd be very irritated if the software did not allow me to edit that line.

Comment: @AndrewThompson The ten lines at the beginning will be set through code by (setText method) and i don't want to allow user to edit that.

Comment: Then use two `JTextArea`s, one that is editable and one that isn't...

Comment: @MadProgrammer Am expecting like a terminal tool, where user can add text only at the end , (e.g) when he connects to a remote computer he can able to see "connecting.." and text like that but he cant edit it.

Comment: For that I'd offer a non-editable text area for the output (all of it) but a text **field** for the input.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out the [Protected Text Component](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/12/21/protected-text-component/) which allows you to protect multiple areas of a Document from change.

Or if you don't need to be able to "select" any of the protected text than a simpler solution is to use a NavigationFilter:

```
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.text.*;

public class NavigationFilterPrefixWithBackspace extends NavigationFilter
{
    private int prefixLength;
    private Action deletePrevious;

    public NavigationFilterPrefixWithBackspace(int prefixLength, JTextComponent component)
    {
        this.prefixLength = prefixLength;
        deletePrevious = component.getActionMap().get("delete-previous");
        component.getActionMap().put("delete-previous", new BackspaceAction());
        component.setCaretPosition(prefixLength);
    }

    @Override
    public void setDot(NavigationFilter.FilterBypass fb, int dot, Position.Bias bias)
    {
        fb.setDot(Math.max(dot, prefixLength), bias);
    }

    @Override
    public void moveDot(NavigationFilter.FilterBypass fb, int dot, Position.Bias bias)
    {
        fb.moveDot(Math.max(dot, prefixLength), bias);
    }

    class BackspaceAction extends AbstractAction
    {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            JTextComponent component = (JTextComponent)e.getSource();

            if (component.getCaretPosition() > prefixLength)
            {
                deletePrevious.actionPerformed( null );
            }
        }
    }

    private static void createAndShowUI()
    {
        JTextField textField = new JTextField("Prefix_", 20);
        textField.setNavigationFilter( new NavigationFilterPrefixWithBackspace(7, textField) );

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Navigation Filter Example");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(textField);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo( null );
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                createAndShowUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Okay, this is slightly hacky...

Basically what this does is installs a "protected" `DocumentFilter`, which will only allow input to put in from a certain point in the `Document`.

It overrides the `JTextArea`'s `insert-break` key binding (<kbd>Enter</kbd>) and records a marker.  The "protected" `DocumentFilter` then ensures that the content does not precede this point

I was forced to implement a `KeyListener` on the field to move the cursor to the end of the input, while the `DocumentFilter` was capable of handling this, it did present some issues with deleting and general usability.  This also ensures that the selection is un-highlighted when new content is added...

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.Action;
import javax.swing.ActionMap;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.text.AbstractDocument;
import javax.swing.text.AttributeSet;
import javax.swing.text.BadLocationException;
import javax.swing.text.DocumentFilter;

public class Terminal {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Terminal();
    }

    public Terminal() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JTextArea terminal = new JTextArea(20, 40);
                ProtectedDocumentFilter.install(terminal);

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(new JScrollPane(terminal));
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public static interface UserInput {

        public int getUserInputStart();

        public void setUserInputStart(int lastPoint);
    }

    public static class DefaultUserInput implements UserInput {

        private final JTextArea textArea;
        private int userInputStart;

        public DefaultUserInput(JTextArea ta) {
            textArea = ta;
            ActionMap am = ta.getActionMap();
            Action action = am.get("insert-break");
            am.put("insert-break", new ProxyAction(action));

            ta.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {

                @Override
                public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
                    if (textArea.getCaretPosition() != textArea.getDocument().getLength()) {
                        textArea.setCaretPosition(textArea.getDocument().getLength());
                    }
                }

            });
        }

        @Override
        public void setUserInputStart(int userInputStart) {
            this.userInputStart = userInputStart;
        }

        @Override
        public int getUserInputStart() {
            return userInputStart;
        }

        public class ProxyAction extends AbstractAction {

            private final Action proxy;

            public ProxyAction(Action proxy) {
                this.proxy = proxy;
            }

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                proxy.actionPerformed(e);

                int range = textArea.getCaretPosition() - userInputStart;
                userInputStart += range;

            }

        }

    }

    public static class ProtectedDocumentFilter extends DocumentFilter {

        protected static void install(JTextArea textArea) {
            UserInput ui = new DefaultUserInput(textArea);
            ((AbstractDocument) textArea.getDocument()).setDocumentFilter(new ProtectedDocumentFilter(ui));
        }

        private UserInput userInput;

        public ProtectedDocumentFilter(UserInput userInput) {
            this.userInput = userInput;
        }

        public UserInput getUserInput() {
            return userInput;
        }

        @Override
        public void insertString(FilterBypass fb, int offset, String string, AttributeSet attr) throws BadLocationException {
            if (offset < getUserInput().getUserInputStart()) {
                offset = fb.getDocument().getLength();
            }

            System.out.println("Insert");

            super.insertString(fb, offset, string, attr);
        }

        @Override
        public void remove(FilterBypass fb, int offset, int length) throws BadLocationException {
            if (offset >= getUserInput().getUserInputStart()) {
                super.remove(fb, offset, length);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void replace(FilterBypass fb, int offset, int length, String text, AttributeSet attrs) throws BadLocationException {
            if (offset < getUserInput().getUserInputStart()) {
                offset = fb.getDocument().getLength();
                length = 0;
            }
            super.replace(fb, offset, length, text, attrs);
            if (text.contains("\n")) {
                int lastPoint = offset + text.lastIndexOf("\n");
                if (lastPoint > getUserInput().getUserInputStart()) {
                    getUserInput().setUserInputStart(lastPoint + 1);
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

This is just an example, you're going to need to play with it and tweak it to meet your own needs....