# Detect when System.in is being queried in java

Tags: java, io, system.in

I am trying to make my own cross platform replacement for the console for testing purposes. I am currently redirecting my system.out and system.in to a GUI Textpane successfully. The system allows me to output and enter text when a Scanner calls next or nextLine etc.

My problem is that currently my Textpane is editable all of the time, but to be more like the windows console I'm emulating I would like it to only be editable when system.in has no available input for the read request. So currently my input stream for system.in is a PipedInputStream. I've tried overwriting the *read* and *available* methods but they seem to only be called after the blocking (waiting for input) has already occurred. I am looking for some way to learn when the system.in is being asked for input prior to blocking so that I can then set my Textpane editable (note that I can easily set it uneditable in the read method).

Comment: You mean something like [this for example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22928666/jtextarea-enable-edit-only-at-the-end-of-document/22929448#22929448) or [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32343355/java-linux-terminal-in-jpanel/32343778#32343778)?

Comment: Depending on how you're "redirecting" `System.in`, you could have a controller which read the content, marked the `Document` in someway and then updated it

Comment: Currently I have a PipedInputStream that is set to System.in (System.setIn(input)). I then have a printWriter for handling writing to the input stream. I am not sure what you mean by controller though.

Comment: I would assume you're writing content to the `System.in` based on what's be typed into the text pane?  You need to determine if the input is from the user or from `System.out`, some kind of "controller" class could be used to this

Comment: It already distinguishes between System.out and System.in - that is not the problem. It is when I do a Scanner reading from system.in it will block if I do scanner.nextLine(). What I'm trying to find is what scanner calls in the inputstream to see if it needs to block or not (I thought it was the available method but that is called after blocking). If it needs to block then I want to set my textpane to be editable so I can enter new input. I don't see how a "controller" object can detect this without some integration into the inputstream/pipedinputstream classes.

Comment: It doesn't, `System.in` is just a blocking call.  This is my point you MUST have something that's reading `System.in` and processing that data, that's you trigger point, that's when you could use something like the examples I've demonstrated, to mark the `Document` so that it's content becomes "protected" - I should clarify that `Scanner` will buffer the input until the requirements of the regular expression are meet, but it's essentially the same.  Something is reading from it, which blocks until something is avaliable